# How to change text of an label from a custom class instantiated dinamically?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a custom class based on panel, which contains a label object.
My class has a constructor with 1 parameter as type String, which has to be the text of my label.

In my main form I make an iteration thru an array of values and I programmatically add my custom panel class with the value from array, passed as parameter.

I see my panel, but the label is not visible.

My Form's code:

```
public partial class frmMain : Form
{
    public frmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }

    private void FrmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i =0; i <= 20; i++) {
            PlaylistRecords pl = new PlaylistRecords("Some name " + i.ToString())
            {
                Name = "Some Name " + i.ToString()
            };
            this.pnlViewer.Controls.Add(pl);
            pl.Left = 2;
            pl.Top = 4 * i + pl.Height * i;
            pl.Invalidate();
        }
        this.pnlViewer.Invalidate();
        this.pnlViewer.AutoScroll = false;
        this.pnlViewer.HorizontalScroll.Enabled = false;
        this.pnlViewer.HorizontalScroll.Maximum = 0;
        this.pnlViewer.AutoScroll = true;
    }
}
```

My PlaylistRecords class:

```
public class PlaylistRecords:Panel 
{
    private Label lblRecordName;

    public static String RecordName { get; set; }

    public PlaylistRecords(
            String RecordName
            )
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(800,50);
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(20,20,20);

        PlaylistRecords.RecordName = RecordName;

        this.lblRecordName.Text = PlaylistRecords.RecordName;

    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.lblRecordName = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // lblRecordName
        // 
        this.lblRecordName.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        this.lblRecordName.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        this.lblRecordName.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(2, 2);
        this.lblRecordName.Name = "lblRecordName";
        this.lblRecordName.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(350, 23);
        this.lblRecordName.TabIndex = 0;
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }
}
```

I see the pl object, but the lblRecordName label does not show.
In debugger I see that lblRecordNmae has correct value.

Why I cannot see it?

Comment: `this.Controls.Add(lblRecordName)`

Comment: pfff... I did not see the missing... Thank you @Ruffus L, it is OK now, it is working.